# iOS Pie Chart Values over lapping Issue

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, charts, pie-chart

I am using iOS library: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

I want to iOS library to draw pie chart. But the issue is, its value labels are overlapping when i have some small amount of data.

Here is my code:

```
pieChart.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: mainCardView.cardBody.frame.width - 20, height: 240)
pieChart.rotationWithTwoFingers = true
pieChart.drawHoleEnabled = false
pieChart.usePercentValuesEnabled = false
pieChart.drawEntryLabelsEnabled = false

pieChart.legend.enabled = true
pieChart.legend.horizontalAlignment = .right
pieChart.legend.verticalAlignment = .center
pieChart.legend.orientation = .vertical
pieChart.legend.xEntrySpace = 2
pieChart.legend.yEntrySpace = 0
pieChart.legend.yOffset = 1

pieChart.legend.font =  UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Regular", size: 8)!
pieChart.legend.drawInside = false
pieChart.legend.font =  UIFont(name: pieChart.legend.font.fontName, size: 12)!
pieChart.legend.formSize = 10
pieChart.legend.maxSizePercent = 0.3
pieChart.animate(xAxisDuration: 0.5, yAxisDuration: 0.5)
pieChart.entryLabelFont = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Regular", size: 8)
pieChart.setExtraOffsets(left: 15, top: 15, right: 15, bottom: 15)
```

and Here is how im setting the data:

```
let set = dataSet as! PieChartDataSet
set.yValuePosition = .outsideSlice
let format = NumberFormatter()
format.numberStyle = .none
set.form = .circle
set.colors = colorArr
set.useValueColorForLine = true

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.multiplier = 1
formatter.numberStyle = .none
formatter.zeroSymbol = ""
formatter.isLenient = true
set.valueLinePart1Length = 0.6
set.valueLinePart2Length = 0.3
set.sliceSpace = 1
set.selectionShift = 0
let data = PieChartData(dataSet: set)
data.setValueTextColor(.black)
data.setValueFormatter(DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: formatter))
chart.data = data
```

Here is the issue image:

[image: pie chart with overlapping text]